# How to combine dynamically generated test suite in python by worker processes created by multiprocessing module

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am running a bunch of worker processes using Python3's multiprocessing. In each worker process I am creating a dynamic Test Case(subclass of unittest.testcase). Under the class I am creating a set of dynamic methods with name "test_". Hence each worker process results in a test_suite. I want to combine test suite from all workers processes and call it using since runner instance from my main so that I can generate a single unit test case HTML report.
I am trying to find out easiest way to do this. I tried to use pickle to convert each test_suite into byte and write it in a seperate file or even shared file using manager queque but that didn't work because it kept giving error "can't get Attribute XXXXX during de-serialization. I think because those dynamically generated classes were not longer available in parent process. Thanks for any suggestion

Here is the container class and worker function which generates the dynamic class and methods.

```
class TestsContainer(unittest.TestCase):
    longMessage = True

def flow_driver(flow_obj, session=None):
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    test = ""
    klassname = 'Test_{0}'.format(str.upper(flow_obj[0]))
    d= {}
    for service in flow_obj[1]:
            result= some_function()
            d['test_service_{0}'.format(service)] = make_test_function(service, result)

    globals()[klassname] = type(klassname, (TestsContainer,), d)
    test = unittest.makeSuite(globals()[klassname])
    test_suite.addTest(test)
    return test_suite

def make_test_function(description, result):
    def test(self):
        #do something
    return test
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this is not possible because the dynamic object(test methods) is no longer available in the parent process so unpicking will not work so I had to change my design to create test methods and class in parent process after capturing run time objects from from child process